# Django change the order of pre_save post_save signals being called when using inlines?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-signals

I have an `Order` (1) and `OrderLine` (n) model, here order can have multiple order-lines. This is *all run* from inside the Django-admin, where the `OrderLine` is setup as part of the `inlines` on `OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)`.

Simplified like this:

```
   class OrderLine(admin.StackedInline):
     pass

   @admin.register(Order)
   class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     inlines = [OrderLine]
```

I registered for the `pre_save` and `post_save` on on both models. Django calls these signals in the following order:

1. Order | pre_save
2. **Order | post_save**
3. OrderLine 1 | pre_save
4. OrderLine 1 | post_save
5. OrderLine 2 | pre_save
6. OrderLine 2 | post_save
7. OrderLine *n* | pre_save
8. OrderLine *n* | post_save

The **issue** I'm having is that I would like to change the order of the signals called, as follows:

1. Order | pre_save
2. OrderLine 1 | pre_save
3. OrderLine 1 | post_save
4. OrderLine 2 | pre_save
5. OrderLine 2 | post_save
6. OrderLine *n* | pre_save
7. OrderLine *n* | post_save
8. **Order | post_save**

Since I need to do a few calculations in each `OrderLine`, and *those results* needs to be used in the `Order` post. But the `post signal` is already been called.

The only solution I see is to call my code on each  `OrderLine post signal`, which is a bit redundant, especially when you have many order-lines.

What would be the best / better way to tackle this?

Comment: You can call saving `OrderLine1,2,N` inside `pre_save` signal of `Order`.

Comment: @SergeyPugach not sure what you mean, how you save the order-lines in the `pre_save`? When I use `post_save` inside the `Order`, I still see the old data of each `OrderLine`. So that doesn't work, which makes sense since I can see the order-lines are updated after the `Order` has been saved.

Comment: Could you add code with your models and that part of code where Order and OrderLine is saved now&

Comment: @SergeyPugach well it's not much use I think. This is al run from within `admin.ModelAdmin`, so not much of code. Other than the 2 functions for `pre_save` and `post_save`. I will updated my question, since this is relevant.

Comment: You have shared content from `admin.py`, but I asked your models from `models.py`.

Comment: @SergeyPugach nothing there just a bunch of fields that are common in a Order/Orderline construction (name, address, order_total, etc..) and on the OrderLine: product_name, quantity, price, vat, total. My problem is in the order which DjangoAdmin fires the signals.  And that the master is called pre *and* post, before the detail rows are updated. Which strikes me as odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been side-tracked, thinking you should solve this via `signals`.

Apparently you can (and should) implement in your `admin` class (admin.ModelAdmin) the following method:

```
 # example
 def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
    super(OrderAdmin, self).save_related(request, form, formsets, change)
    # get the master obj
    order = form.instance
    order.total = Decimal.from_float(0.0)
    for ol in order.order_lines.all():
        order.total += ol.total order.total
```

This is called after all related objects are updated.